# Exception self-handler in c using Assembly

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, exception

I create a self exception handler by using assembly in c file by this code:

```
__asm 
    {
        pushad
        mov esi, offset Handler 
        push esi 
        push dword ptr fs:[0] 
        mov dword ptr fs:[0], esp
        push u32Param
        call pFunc;
        jmp NoException

Handler:

        mov esp, [esp + 8]
        pop dword ptr fs:[0]
        add esp, 4
        popad
        mov eax, 0x80000000     
        jmp ExceptionHandled

NoException:

        pop dword ptr fs:[0]
        add esp, 40

ExceptionHandled:
    }
```

This code is simple exception handling in assembly.
This code works in new created vc project.
But in my project it make an exception and vc says that there is an invalid exception handler.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Try to get a disassembly of a simple exception handler compiled by vc++ to see what entry/exit code blocks are injected. (equivalent of -S in gcc -- objdump -d file.o will also do). It's also possible that there is no special entry/exit code in the routine per se, but that you are required to insert an entry point to your routine as a signal handler.

Comment: I have seen the generated assembly generated by vc but the problem is not in assembly source, it doesn't work in my big project that is a console application, when i create a new project (no matter Win32/Console) , it works!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are following [this article](http://www.rohitab.com/structured-exception-handling-in-assembly-language), which it seems you are, then why aren't you properly restoring the stack as shown in the code there?

The code in the article:

```
18  NoException&;Handler:                ;;No Exception Occured
19      pop dword ptr fs:[0]            ;;Restore Old Exception Handler
20      add esp, 32 + 4                 ;;ESP value before SEH was set. 32 for pushad and ...
21  ExceptionHandled&;Handler:           ;;...4 for push offset Handler. (No Restore State)
22                                      ;;Exception has been handled, or no exception occured
```

Your code:

```
NoException:

        pop dword ptr fs:[0]
        add esp, 8

ExceptionHandled:
```

32 in that code is to undo `pushad`, 4 is to undo `push esi`. Why do you have 8? 32 + 4 ≠ 8.

If that's how you want to remove `u32Param` from the stack (in case `pFunc` doesn't do it for you), then you should do it between these two lines:

```
    call pFunc;
    add esp, 4
    jmp NoException
```

My version:

```
// file: tst.c
// compile with Open Watcom C/C++ 1.9: wcl386.exe /q /we /wx tst.c
// ditto with debug info: wcl386.exe /q /we /wx /d2 tst.c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned __stdcall func(volatile unsigned* p)
{
  return *p;
}

unsigned blah(unsigned (__stdcall *pFunc)(volatile unsigned*), volatile unsigned* u32Param)
{
  unsigned result = 0;

  __asm 
  {
      pushad
//      mov esi, offset Handler // Open Watcom C/C++ says Handler is undefined
//      push esi 

//      lea eax, blah
//      add eax, Handler - blah // this difference doesn't come out correct with Open Watcom C/C++
//      add eax, 78 // 78 is Handler - blah // this is unreliable
//      push eax

      push 0xFDCB4321
      jmp GetHandlerAddr
  GotHandlerAddr:
      pop eax
      add esp, 4
      push eax

      push dword ptr fs:[0] 
      mov dword ptr fs:[0], esp
      push u32Param
      call dword ptr [pFunc]

      jmp NoException

  GetHandlerAddr:
      call Handler // this will place &Handler on the stack
  Handler:
      cmp dword ptr [esp + 4], 0xFDCB4321
      je GotHandlerAddr

      mov esp, [esp + 8]
      pop dword ptr fs:[0]
      add esp, 4
      popad
      mov eax, 0x80000000     
      jmp ExceptionHandled

  NoException:

      pop dword ptr fs:[0]
      add esp, 32 + 4

  ExceptionHandled:

      mov result, eax
  }

  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  volatile unsigned n = 0x113355AA;
  printf("%08X\n", func(&n));
  printf("%08X\n", blah(&func, &n));
  printf("%08X\n", blah(&func, (volatile unsigned*)0));
  printf("%08X\n", blah(&func, (volatile unsigned*)0));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
113355AA
113355AA
80000000
80000000
```

Comment: You are right, I used the article and change it to get parameter from input use for the function that i want to run safe.And Also you are right for correcting stack, I have removed pusha and popa but returned it back for test to get chance of running correctly.  Unfortunately the problem is not on the stack, the vc debugger says "An invalid exception handler found" when the exception occur. It never jump to the handler, so the stack is not important until such jump.

Comment: What if your run the program not under the debugger? I have no problems with that here (using Open Watcom C/C++, though).

Comment: It will crash. I 'm confused! This way is the most popular way to have self-handler, I saw it lots of time on so many malware assemblies. But I can't find what is the problem.

Comment: I've added my version of the code. It's practically identical to yours save the compiler differences.